# Does the holiday special episode of Sherlock relate to the previous season?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

I have just noticed that there is a special episode of *Sherlock* called "The Abominable Bride". Does it relate plot-wise to the previous season (3)?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is.

Beware, **spoilers with regard to the concept of the episode** in this [excerpt from The Verge's review](http://www.theverge.com/2016/1/4/10704192/sherlock-the-abominable-bride-review):

> This isn’t a true alternate reality, though: having had his season-ending suicidal mission cancelled, **the present-day Sherlock has taken a potent — and potentially lethal — drug cocktail. It’s heightening an elaborate fantasy within his "mind palace,"** and it revolves around an old case that he’s using to **solve the mystery of his nemesis Moriarty’s (Andrew Scott) apparent return.**